# Terminology problem

Tags: group-theory, terminology

I am not a mathematician, please forgive my incorrect language. My question involves terminology. If a finite non-abelian group G is represented by a set of unitary operators ${\mathbf G}_r, r = 1,2,..., |G|$, on a Hilbert space, it is sometimes advantageous to introduce group projectors ${\mathbf P}_{Qk}, {\mathbf P}_{Q'k'},...$, concerned with individual (diagonal) rows of the individual irreps Q, Q',...:

$${\mathbf P}_{Qk} = \frac{d_Q}{|G|} \sum_{r=1}^{|G|} Q_{kk}^{*}(G_r){\mathbf G}_r,$$

where $Q_{kk}(G_r)$ is the k-th diagonal element of the irreducible matrix Q of dimensions $d_Q \times d_Q$ representing r-th element of G. The eigensubspaces of the individual projectors ${\mathbf P}_{Qk}$ are sometimes called symmetry species if G describes a geometric symmetry of an object (a molecule, for instance). Is there any special term describing various symmetry species of the same Q but different k? Symmetry subspecies? Partner species? Thank you for your possible answer.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Math.SE! Here's a quick-guide on how to write math here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Also, we usually call this **terminology**, not **nomenclature**.

Comment: Thanks, I have just changed nomenclature to terminology.